# Jquery Overlay Default Positioning

Tags: jquery, css, positioning, jquery-tools

I have a jquery tools overlay one my wordpress blog, and I have the code that keeps it in position where I want it to be when I resize the window. But on first click to load the overlay, it displays in the center of the page, I need it set to the left an additional 250px.

heres my code for the positioning:

```
$(document).ready(function() { setDef() });

function setDef() {
var w = $('.simple_overlay').width();//get width of overlay
    var h = $('.simple_overlay').height(); //get height of overlay
    var l = ($(window).width() - w) / 2 + 250;  //calculate left property
    var t = ($(window).height() - h) / 2  //calculate top property
$('.simple_overlay').css({ 'left': l })
}
```

the above should calculate the default position (centered) then add 250px, but its not adding the 250. 
The code below adds the 250 when the window is resized.

```
$(window).resize(function() { rePosition() });

function rePosition() {
    var w = $('.simple_overlay').width();//get width of overlay
    var h = $('.simple_overlay').height(); //get height of overlay
    var l = ($(window).width() - w) / 2 + 250;  //calculate left property
    var t = ($(window).height() - h) / 2  //calculate top property
    $('.simple_overlay').css({ 'left': l })
```

I think I need to use something other than (document).ready

Ps- You can close the overlay by clicking in the top right corner, theres no visual indicator right now but your cursor will change.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get rid of the `setDef()` function and put a call to `rePosition()` in your click event handler on the #search-box-nav image (or whichever element has a click handler).

If you refresh your page and run the following code in the console then it mimics doing that...

```
$("#search-box-nav img").bind("click", function() { rePosition(); });
```

Comment: I put that code in the function but no luck. Played with it a bit and still got no luck. The element that loads the overlay is img[rel]... Here is the script that calls the overlay:

    $(document).ready(function() {
 $("img[rel]").overlay({
  fixed:false,
  top:160,

Comment: Something, somewhere, is binding a click event to the images (or the containers).  In that there will be something that fades in the overlay div.  The line after `fadeIn()` (or similar), put `rePosition();`.  The code I gave you above was just how I tested it on your site without you adding it to your script.  If you open your site, don't click the button, and then run that code in the console, when you click the button afterwards it's in the correct place.  I was just letting you know that I had tested it and it does work.

Comment: Okay - I can see you added `$("#ab").bind("click", function() { rePosition(); });` You need to move that inside a `document.ready` block so that it only runs once everything is loaded.  It's currently running before the image is on the page.  That script will only bind to the about button though, not the other buttons, so you'll need the code I gave you above to make it work on all the buttons.

Comment: My Hero! put it in a document.ready and it works now. Thanks so much for the help!!!